# Receiving undefined method `mood_id' for #<Profile:0x611b5d8> for associated Profile model Model Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, simple-form

I'm having trouble with connecting the profile model to the moods model, and then saving the mood's id to the user's profile. I would be grateful if you can help me resolve this issue.

_mood_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, url: current_user, html: {multipart: true}, layout: :horizontal) do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |n| %>
        <%= n.label :mood_id, 'Select a mood' %>
        <%= n.collection_select :mood_id, Mood.all, :id, :name %>
        <%= f.submit 'Change Mood', class: 'btn btn-info-outline' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

profile.rb
belongs_to :mood

mood.rb
has_many :profiles
```

Server Development Log

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `mood_id' for #<Profile:0x611b5d8>:
  activemodel (4.2.3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
  ransack (1.7.0) lib/ransack/helpers/form_builder.rb:10:in `value'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_select.rb:16:in `block in render'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_select.rb:16:in `render'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:202:in `collection_select'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:789:in `collection_select'
  app/views/users/shared/_mood_form.html.erb:4:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_users_shared__mood_form_html_erb__906227000_76706760'
  actionview
```

migration file

```
class CreateMoods < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :moods do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :mood
      t.references :profile, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `belongs_to :mood`, you should add `mood_id` integer field into `profiles` database table:

```
 class AddMoodToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_column :profiles, :mood_id, :integer
   end
 end
```

Comment: Oops. I'm obviously exhausted, I clearly forgot to add the id. Thanks.